# how to call UITextFieldDelegate in UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate, swift-extensions

I am not able to call the delegate method of UITextField, when I click one textfield in my View. 
`func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool` any idea?

```
import UIKit
class CustomUIViewScreen: UIView {  
 override func awakeFromNib() {
...
 textField.delegate = self
}

 override func didMoveToWindow() {
    if (self.window != nil) {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name: .UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide), name: .UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
    }
}

@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        if self.frame.origin.y == 0{
            self.frame.origin.y -= keyboardSize.height - 60
        }
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
            self.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
}

 @objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        let info = notification.userInfo! as NSDictionary
        let animationDuration = info.object(forKey: UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: animationDuration as! TimeInterval) {
             if self.frame.origin.y != 0 {
                self.frame.origin.y += keyboardSize.height
                self.layoutIfNeeded()
            }
        }
    }
}
}

extension CustomUIViewScreen : UITextFieldDelegate {
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    let nextTag = textField.tag + 1
    let nextResponder = textField.superview?.viewWithTag(nextTag) as UIResponder!

    if (nextResponder != nil) {
        nextResponder?.becomeFirstResponder()
    } else {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
    }
    return false
}
}
```

Comment: Are you loading your custom view (`CustomUIViewScreen `) from code or from xib/storyboard?

Comment: CustomUIViewScreen from XIB i am loading it. @pkc456

Comment: Do you want event on textfield click or end Editing of the field?

Comment: end editing should be @NikunjDamani

Comment: Are you using return button ?

Comment: yes let me add the whole logic one min, the point is appearing when i want to hide the keyboard after moving down the View. @NikunjDamani

Comment: How many textfields are there because in the code you are assigning delegate to only one textfield

Comment: i have 3 textfields @NikunjDamani

Comment: Have you assigned the delegate all of them? you should try

Comment: yes i am using this for assigning ` for textField in textFields {} `@NikunjDamani

Answer (score 0):

When you clicked on textfield, then textfield becomes first responder and following delegate method called:-

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField)
```

`textFieldShouldReturn` method calls when user press return button

Official link:- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfielddelegate/1619590-textfielddidbeginediting

Comment: this is also not working for my situation. I have a moving up function for the View. I cannot resign anything using this..

Comment: @DicleY can you elaborate what you want exactly

Comment: So when i move up the view everything is okay but when i click any textfield while its move up, to move down, keyboard is still there, its not showing off . @Sh_Khan

Comment: To hide the keyboard while scrolling, implement the `scrollDidScroll` delegate method, and hide the keyboard there using `textField.resignFirstResponder()`

Comment: according to your code keyboard to hide it must be the bottom most textfeild

Comment: what do you mean bottom most textfield @Sh_Khan

Comment: from your code inside return func , i conclude that you have more then 1 textfeild that when user presses return in 1 you get the next if it exists and make it becomeResponder